# Hangfire: huge latency when using MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, hangfire

I'm using `HangFire` with `MySQL` backend. When I do simple

```
 var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
                () => Debug.WriteLine("Test"));
```

I see a delay of 5-10 seconds, even though I've set the polling rate to 1 sec:

```
app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
            {
                SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                ServerCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            });
```

My setup is the most simple as possible - server and client on the same machine, queue is empty. I was expecting delays not bigger than 1 second.

I do not plan to use distributed servers, can I force somehow a server to immediately start the task? I assume if I switch to in-memory storage for hangfire it would start tasks immediately, - I found https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage but it is stated that it should not be used in production. What are my options to optimize latency?

Comment: @mason The only reason why I want memory storage system for `Hangfire` is to be able to start tasks immediately (which I assume it will). Otherwise I'm completely fine with `mysql` backend. So this is actually one question, I'll try to rephrase it

Comment: You should monitor queries to your mysql server to see if hangfire issues a polling query every second. Also, hangfire fires more than 10 queries to handle a job. You should have a look at the time consumed here (or if connection is not pooled and it etablishes a new conneciton to mysql on each query)

Comment: Any lack with this? Have a similar problem.

Comment: @Alex No, I ended up changing my architecture and not relying on the immediate task execution